# Angular does not show variable the right way it shows [object object] after http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi im using some external api to get a city name in php like so:

```
// Get city name
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://------------&fourpp=1106',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'RingNBring'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$city = json_decode($resp);
if ($city->status == 'ok') {
  foreach ($city->results[0] as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k == 'city') {
      $data['city'] = $v;
    }
  }
}
```

im encoding the return and the return object in angular (console.log) looks like this

```
Object {0: "Yes", cart: Array[4], loc: Object, city: "'s-Gravendeel"}
0: "Yes"cart: Array[4]city: "'s-Gravendeel"loc: Object__proto__: Object main.js:106
```

now i set this in the scope: `$scope.city = data.city;`

now in the look i do:

```
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Woonplaats" name="city" ng-model="checkoutForm.city" value="{{city}}"  required>
```

but i only see `[object Object]` in the input field? console.log shows the right value when i show $scope.city

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the `value`- `ng-model` does that for you.

Also, not sure where you're setting `checkoutForm` - as indicated in your current `ng-model`

you have indicated that you're setting `$scope.city = data.city` - so i can only assume that your http request returns the object `data`

If this is the case, then set, for example `$scope.myData = data;` and then your `ng-model` can be `ng-model="myData.city` - notice it is dot-notation; `myData` is your data `.` the property you want to assign to  = `myData.city`

If this isn't helping, please show your `js` where you retrieve and assign your data to a scope property

Comment: yes you're right. in angular u can set $scope.checkoutForm.city = data.city; (on the model) this works....

Comment: so did this help you're issue?